# Conditional Formatting Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, conditional-formatting

Can someone help me with how to replicate this conditional formatting formula in Python using Openpyxl?

`=AND(RIGHT(B$7;9)="(Message)";B8<>"";A8=C8;C8="")`
If true,color the cell red.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just delimit the double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of and ways to do this and lots of examples, below is one option;
cf_range will be the cell range to apply this conditional formatting to

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import fills
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule

work_book = load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
sheet = work_book.active

cf_range = '$A1'

sheet.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range,
                                 FormulaRule(
                                     formula=["AND(RIGHT(B$7,9)=\"(Message)\";B8<>\"\";A8=C8;C8=\"\")"],
                                     fill=fills.PatternFill("solid", bgColor="FF0000"),
                                     stopIfTrue=False
                                     )
                                 )

work_book.save('foo.xlsx')
```